# Get data from B method to A method without using Session in C#?

Tags: c#, session

How can i get my **master_handler** `method` handler_response data to **get_data** method without using `session` in `C#`.

Currently i getting data by using session, i want to get **handler_response** data in **string response** under GET_DATA() method without using `session`.

How can do this please help

My code is

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GET_DATA()
{
    string Search = "1";
    master_handler(Search);

    string response = string.Empty;
    response = (string)HttpContext.Current.Session["HANDLER_RESPONSE"]; // getting handler_response here
    HttpContext.Current.Session["obj_GET_FLIGHT_DATA"] = response;
    return response;
}

public static string master_handler(string dt)
{
    string handler_response= string.Empty;
    LibraryCaller.Master_Handler MH = new LibraryCaller.Master_Handler();
    string get_api_data = MH.Search(dt);
    JObject jObj = JObject.Parse(get_api_data);
    handler_response= jObj.ToString();
    HttpContext.Current.Session["HANDLER_RESPONSE"] = handler_response; // here currently using sesson
    return handler_response;
}
```

Comment: You could cache the value and retrieve it from there

Answer (score 0):

Cache the value instead:

```
Cache.Insert("HANDLER_RESPONSE", handler_response);
```

To retrieve it use:

```
    string handler_response;
handler_response = (string)Cache["HANDLER_RESPONSE"];
```

That's the simplest way to do it via caching, read up on it as theres a lot more to it.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this by using class.

```
public class handler
{
    public string data_handler(string dt)
    {
         string handler_response= string.Empty;
         LibraryCaller.Master_Handler MH = new LibraryCaller.Master_Handler();
         string get_api_data = MH.Search(dt);
         JObject jObj = JObject.Parse(get_api_data);
         handler_response= jObj.ToString();
         HttpContext.Current.Session["HANDLER_RESPONSE"] = handler_response; // here currently using sesson
         return handler_response;
    }
}
```

and access data

```
    handler h = new handler();
    response = h.data_handler(search);
```

Comment: Seems overkill to me if that's the sole reason for creating the class.